# ThemeProvider & prop theme from Styled-Components on Nextjs 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, next.js13

I'm having some problems generating a theme with styled-components. The error at first seemed like a simple fix, but I can't figure out what the problem is.
[NextJS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRXlZ.png)

In theory I think I have everything configured correctly but I don't understand why I can't access the palette prop, any idea why?

**BodyComponent.tsx**

```
"use client";
// Vendors
import { PropsWithChildren, ReactElement } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
// styles
import AppTheme from "@/theme/ui.theme";

const BodyComponent = ({children, className}: PropsWithChildren<{className: string}>): ReactElement => {
  
  return (
    <body className={className}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={AppTheme}>
        { children }
      </ThemeProvider>
    </body>
  );
};

export default BodyComponent;
```

**Theme.ts**

```
const mode_colors = {
  light: '255 255 255',
  dark: '0 0 0',
}

const status_colors = {
  colorSucessA: '#81c784',
  colorSucessB: '#66bb6a',
  colorSucessC: '#388e3c',
  colorWarningA: '#ffb74d',
  colorWarningB: '#ffa726',
  colorWarningC: '#f57c00',
  colorSeveralA: '#e57373',
  colorSeveralB: '#f44336',
  colorSeveralC: '#d32f2f',
};

const app_colors = {
  primaryColorA: '#FFC377',
  primaryColorB: '#FFAD45',
  primaryColorC: '#FF8E00',
  contrastColorA: '#d4dc85',
  contrastColorB: '#ccd75b',
  contrastColorC: '#2596be',
}

const AppTheme = {
  palette: {
    ...app_colors,
    ...status_colors,
    ...mode_colors,
  }
};

export default AppTheme;
```

**StyleComponent file**

```
'use client';
// Vendors
import { css } from "styled-components";

const rootStyle = () => {
  return css`
    :root {
      --mode-background: rgb(${({theme}) => theme.palette.dark});
      --pattern-background: url(/patterns/graph-paper-dark.svg);
      --font-color: rgb(${({theme}) => theme.palette.light});
      
      @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
        --mode-background: rgb(${({theme}) => theme.palette.light});
        --pattern-background: url(/patterns/graph-paper-light.svg);
        --font-color: rgb(${({theme}) => theme.palette.dark});
      }
    }
  `;
};
```

I've tried modifying the object so that it only has the colours, declaring it in the file where I call ThemeProvider and modifying the hierarchy of the elements to see if it affects anything.

Also I tried to define the type `DefaultTheme` of styled-components.

```
// Vendors
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";
// Constants
import colors from "./constants/colors.constants";

const AppTheme: DefaultTheme = {
  palette: colors,
};

export default AppTheme;
```

Comment: You've written `theme.colors` instead of `theme.palette`. That seems the likely problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code file over some changes I made to see if it would fix it.

Comment: Can you provide the useage of `rootStyle`? Need to see the context of where that is being called.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem, my `GlobalsComponent` with the styles was outside the provider *facepalm* I didn't notice until you told me about the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the hierarchy of the elements, in my case I had a component for loading the global styles, all the files that read the `theme` have to be inside the `ThemeProvider`. My `ThemeProvider` comes from the `BodyComponent`.

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <BodyComponent className={inter.className}>
        <GlobalStylesComponent />
        {children}
      </BodyComponent>
    </html>
  )
}
```